# Laravel retrieve data from multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel

Its my Db structure 
I have a student table as

```
students 
+-------+--------+----------+
|id     |  name  | group_id | 
+-------+--------+----------+                
|1      |  ali   |     1    |
|2      |  ahmad |     2    |
+-------+--------+----------+

groups
+------+-------------+
|id    |  group_name |
+------+-------------+                
|1     |     A       |
|2     |     B       |
+------+-------------+
```

Now I have to show Name from `student` table and group_name from `Groups`

**StudentController**

```
{
        $students = Student::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        return view('student.index')->with(compact('students'));
    }
```

**My View**

```
@foreach($students as $student)

<td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
<td {{ $student->group_name }} </td>
```

Please help me to retrieve record from both tables I try with different methods but failed

Answer (score 2):

You need to add relation method to the `Student` class:

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
}
```

where `Group` is a model's class of a `groups` table.

Then in the controller:

```
{
    $students = Student::orderBy('id', 'desc')->with('group')->get();
    return view('student.index')->with(compact('students'));
}
```

and in the view:

```
@foreach($students as $student)

<td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
<td {{ $student->group->name }} </td>
```

Comment: what do you mean by student class where i have to add relation ?@Fillip Koblariski

Comment: Here: `Student::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();` <- `Student` is a class that extends the eloquent model's

Comment: it says public undefined 
syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) @Fillip Koblariski

Comment: Show your `Student` class

Comment: '<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'group_id'];
}
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Groups::class);
}'

Comment: Now its saying
Trying to get property of non-object
at this line {{ $student->group->name }}
@Fillip koblariski

Answer (score 0):

One student belongs to only one group. so, relationship between the student and group is one to one.

In Students.php Model

```
public function group(){
   return $this->hasOne(Group::class,'id','group_id');
}
```

and in view you can get group name as

```
@foreach($students as $student)
      <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $student->group->name }}</td>
@endforeach
```